# Lower bound for difference of probabilities of a same event under two different distributions

Tags: distance, kullback-leibler, probability-inequalities, hellinger

Say $P$ and $Q$ are two probabilities distributions on $[n]$. I can upper bound the difference of the probability of an event $A$ under $P$ and $Q$ by the total variation distance between $P$ and $Q$.
$$\forall A, |P(A) - Q(A)| < ||P - Q||_{TV}$$
and this TV can be expressed nicely in other ways, and further upper bounded by some other quantities that can be easy(ier) to compute.

But what about some lower bounding techniques on $|P(A) - Q(A)|$ ?

Comment: Based on the generality of your question, the best possible answer is $0$ unless strong assumptions are made about these distributions.

Comment: What particular sort of assumption would be helpful in this case ? My wish is to derive the largest lower bounds possible. Since P and Q have finite support, I was hoping to get something that depends on the weights.

Comment: I can imagine a whole host of assumptions that might yield some information. (They would all have to be strong ones: for instance, if you cannot rule out the possibility that there exists $1\le i \le n$ for which $P(i)=Q(i)$, then the lower bound must be zero. But even if you can rule out that possibility, there may be other subsets $A$ for which $P$ and $Q$ give the same probability.)   But that doesn't matter--what matters is that you disclose the assumptions you can make for *your* problem.  Please don't make us guess them!